# SD card socket with MMC and Atmel

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, atmel, sd

I'm trying to include an [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital) slot in one of my designs. The whole SD format seems confused at best, and I can't seem to find a definitive answer to what I need to wire up.

Apparently the easiest way to do it is with [MMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiMediaCard) ([SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus)) on my microcontroller. There are already prebuilt libraries for this use.

In hardware, I'm planning on using [a socket from Yamaichi Electronics](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Yamaichi-Electronics/FPS009-3202-BL/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMuJakaoiLiBpkqkV16wW/QuPlWwBHu/niU=) , FPS009-3202-BL, along with a [TXB0104](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txb0104.pdf) level shifter to handle 5 V to 3.3 V signal conversion. The microcontroller is an [ATtiny4313](http://www.atmel.com/devices/attiny4313.aspx), which has MOSI on pin 17, MISO on pin 18, and SCK on pin 19. I'm not sure what to do with SS or even if I've wired it correctly. Here's a screenshot of what I have so far:

[image]

How can I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

So if anyone finds this later, I eventually found the answer on this page.
http://www.ladyada.net/make/logshield/design.html

I hope it helps someone.